# Visual Studio 2010 Snippets - Current Date

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I'm making a snippet for a file header in Visual Studio 2010. I want the date to match whenever the snippet was executed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware your not able to execute any code in a snippet, such as

```
DateTime.Now()
```

And there is no other way to do it. I've looked into this as I was trying to do something similar myself.

Sorry!

The alternative is as @AJM suggests to write a macro and assign it to a keyboard shortcut

Comment: Thats what I found out too :-( You can use DateTime.Now() in a macro then assign a keyboard shortcut..