# how to create code snippet that includes date

Tags: c#, code-snippets

I am getting tired of adding the date when I add a comment about some change I am making in the code.  I am required to start comments like this:

// 14/03/24 fj: some comment

I don't need to repeat it on continued lines, just the first.

I am trying to create a code snippet to do this, but can't figure out how to 
reference the date inside my CDATA block.  I tried searching, but couldn't find anything.  Any ideas/links/etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469324/visual-studio-2010-snippets-current-date .

Comment: this seems like the kind of thing source control is for, not inline comments :O

Comment: This is why God gave us version control systems.  You can always check to see when the comment was created that way.  Also, no links.  You can create a simple console app that copies "// {0}  {1}:" (current date, current user values passed in) to the clipboard.  Add it as an external program, map it to a key combo.  Then all you have to do is, for example, shift-ctrl-V (runs app), ctrl-v (creates comment).  Type away.

Comment: We use version control and I agree. But note the above phrase: "I am required to..."  Will consider your suggestion though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script for yourself, as code snippets have very limited logic available to them. Using AutoHotkey has the added bonus of working *everywhere*, and not being language specific.

Here's the AutoHotkey script you could use:

```
::\stamp::
FormatTime, TimeString,, ShortDate
Send %TimeString% fj
return
```

Typing `\stamp` will replace `\stamp` with `3/24/2015 fj`

Comment: this seems like a valid way to solve OPs problem... why the downvote?